# get nested value ansible

Tags: linux, ansible, vmware

I'm trying to get vm ip-address to write it into hosts file.
But i'm getting all array instead of one value. How can i get it?

```
- name: Gather some info from a guest using the vSphere API output schema
  community.vmware.vmware_guest_info:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    datacenter: "{{ datacenter }}"
    validate_certs: no
    name: "{{ vm_name }}"
    schema: "vsphere"
    properties: "guest.ipAddress"
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: info

- name: Print all available facts
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: info
```

My result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "info": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "instance": {
            "guest": {
                "ipAddress": "10.10.5.167"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-nested-variables

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use the dot notation e.g in your case :

```
- name: Print ip address
  debug:
    var: info.instance.guest.ipAddress
```